# Property of bounded linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, solution-verification

I came up with a property of bounded linear operators and i am not sure if it is correct,because the proof seems easy.

> Let $T:X \to Y$ be a linear operator with the property that: if $x_n \in X$ a sequence such that $x_n \to 0$ then $||Tx_n||$ is bounded (as a sequence of real numbers).Then $T$ is a bounded operator.

I proved it twice,with different proofs.

$\textbf{Proof 1}$ Assume that $T$ is not bounded.Then exists a sequence $x_n \in X$ such that $||x_n||=1,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $||Tx_n|| \geq n^2$.

Then $y_n:=\frac{x_n}{n} \to 0$ thus $||Ty_n||$ is bounded,by hypothesis.

But $||Ty_n|| \geq n,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$,which is a contradiction.

$\textbf{Proof 2}$ Assume that is not continuous at some point $x \in X$.

Thus exists $c>0$ with the property: exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $||x_n-x||<\frac{1}{n}$ and $||T(x_n-x)|| \geq c,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Define $y_n=\frac{||x_n-x||}{\sqrt{||x_n-x||}}=\sqrt{||x_n-x||} <\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$

But $||Ty_n|| \geq c\sqrt{n} \to +\infty$ which is a contradiction.

Are these proofs correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think Proof 1 looks okay. For Proof 2 I would like to note, that if $X$ is not the real numbers, then $Ty_n$ is not in $Y$ ($y_n\in\mathbb{R}\neq X$). Then $\Vert Ty_n\Vert$ is in the operator norm, and since you assume $T$ not to be bounded (equivalent to continuity (in one point) ), it is obvious, that $\Vert Ty_n\Vert$ is unbounded.

Comment: Why do you doubt the correctness in you have an easy proof?